# Почему один и тот же запрос в postgresql и sqlalchemy выдают разные результаты?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Столкнулся с проблемой при выполнении запроса на прямую в postgresql возвращается следующий результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если этот же запрос выполнить через sqlalchemy:

```
        expression = """
SELECT C.*, m2.text
FROM client c
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(complaint_date) AS latest_timestamp
    FROM message_to_web
    GROUP BY user_id
) m ON c.client_id = m.user_id
JOIN message_to_web m2 ON m.user_id = m2.user_id AND m.latest_timestamp = m2.complaint_date;
        """
        result = await session.execute(text(expression))
        user_list = result.scalars().all()
```

Получаю просто список id:

```
[
    100000300,
    100000360,
    6373403021,
    100000485
]
```

В чем может быть проблема?

вот код моделей:

```
class MessageToWeb(Base):
    """Таблица сообщений между пользователем и менеджером

    Атрибуты:
        - message_id (int): id сообщения
        - user_id (ind): id пользователя
        - master_id (ind): id мастера
        - text (str): Текст сообщения
        - destination (str): Адресат сообщения. Если сообщение от клиента менеджеру - meneger, отк менеджера клиенту - client
    """
    
    __tablename__ = "message_to_web"

    message_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("client.client_id"), autoincrement=False, nullable=False)
    master_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey("master.master_id"), autoincrement=False, nullable=False)
    text = Column(String(1200), nullable=False)
    destination = Column(String(400), nullable=False)
    complaint_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    

# Модели бота
class Client(Base):
    """
    Таблица с информацией о клиенте.

    Атрибуты:
    - client_id (int): ID клиента в Telegram.
    - username (str): Логин клиента в Telegram.
    - client_url (str): Ссылка на клиента в Telegram.
    - name (str): Имя клиента.
    - city (str): Город клиента.
    - tattoo_type (str): Тип татуировки клиента (цветная/одноцветная/оба варианта).
    - is_advertising_allowed (bool): Флаг, указывающий, согласен ли пользователь получать
     рекламные сообщения. True - согласен, False - не согласен.
    - is_model (bool): Флаг, указывающий, согласен ли пользователь быть моделью
     (делать тату по себестоимости). True - согласен, False - не согласен.
    - is_bot_usage_consent (bool): Флаг, указывающий согласен ли пользователь использовать бота.
     True - согласен, False - не согласен.
    - is_blocked (bool): Флаг, указывающий, заблокирован ли пользователь в боте.
     True - заблокирован, False - не заблокирован.
    """

    __tablename__ = "client"

    client_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    username = Column(String(60), nullable=True)
    client_url = Column(String(130), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(130), nullable=False)
    city = Column(String(70), nullable=False)
    tattoo_type = Column(String(60), nullable=False)
    date_of_reg = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    is_advertising_allowed = Column(Boolean, default=True, nullable=False)
    is_model = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    is_bot_usage_consent = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    is_blocked = Column(Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)

    
    complaints = relationship(
        "Complaints", back_populates="client", cascade="delete, delete-orphan"
    )
    likes = relationship(
        "Likes", back_populates="client", cascade="delete, delete-orphan"
    )
    contact_requests = relationship(
        "ContactRequests", back_populates="client", cascade="delete, delete-orphan"
    )
    styles = relationship(
        "ClientStyles", back_populates="client", cascade="delete, delete-orphan"
    )
    messages = relationship(
        "MessageToWeb", backref="client", cascade="delete, delete-orphan", 
    )
```

Comment: Включить General Log и смотреть, что на самом деле добралось до MySQL.

Comment: Какая версия sqlAlchemy, они сильно отличаются

Comment: Имейте ввиду, что ваш алиас `C` postgresql читает как `c`, а вот как его интерпретирует SQLAlchemy не знаю. Если Вы хотите чтобы `C` было `C` то пишите `"C"`

Comment: полагаю прооблема в `result.scalars().all()`, насколько я помню метод `scalars()` берет только первые столбы результата, попробуйте просто `result.all()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема заключалась в функции scalars(). Она возвращает только первые элементы списка, получаемого от запроса.